# Recursive nested directives with transclude injecting wrong parent controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working on an idea to define a settings modal but I'm pretty new to angular and can't get my head around the recursive nested directive to build a tree in my scopes to represent the html structure.

**HTML**

*index.html* Part

```
<wizard title="Settings Title" back-button-label="Close Wizard">
  <wizard-option title="Account Settings" partial="account_settings_form"></wizard-option>
  <wizard-option title="API Settings">
    <wizard-option title="API Partner 1" partial="partner1_form"></wizard-option>
    <wizard-option title="API Partner 2" partial="partner2_form"></wizard-option>
  </wizard-option>
  <wizard-option title="Notification Settings" partial="notification_settings_form"></wizard-option>
</wizard>
```

*wizard.html*

```
<header>
    <div class='back'>{{backButtonLabel}}</div>
    <div class='title'>{{title}}</div>
</header>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="option in controller.options">
            <a href="" ng-click="select(option)">{{option.title}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div ng-transclude></div>
```

*wizard-option.html*

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="option in controller.options">
            <a href="" ng-click="select(option)">{{option.title}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div ng-transclude></div>
```

**Directive Code**

In coffeescript, sorry

```
angular.module('app.directives.wizard', ['templates']).directive 'wizard', ->
  restrict: 'E'
  transclude: true
  scope:
    title: '@'
    backButtonLabel: '@'
  controller: 'WizardCtrl'
  templateUrl: 'wizard.html'

angular.module('app.directives.wizard', ['templates']).directive 'wizard-option', ->
  require: ['^wizard', '?^wizardOption']
  restrict: 'E'
  transclude: true
  scope:
    title: '@'
  controller: 'WizardCtrl'
  link: (scope, element, attrs, controllers) ->
    [parentWizardCtrl, parentWizardOptionCtrl] = controllers

    console.log "S: #{scope.title}##{scope.$id} - W: #{parentWizardCtrl.$scope.title}##{parentWizardCtrl.$scope.$id} - O: #{parentWizardOptionCtrl.$scope.title}##{parentWizardOptionCtrl.$scope.$id}"        

  templateUrl: 'wizard-option.html'
```

**Console Output**

```
S: Account Settings#01T - W: Settings Title#01R - O: Account Settings#01T
S: API Partner 1#01V - W: Settings Title#01R - O: API Partner 1#01V
S: API Partner 2#01X - W: Settings Title#01R - O: API Partner 2#01X
S: Notification Settings#01Z - W: Settings Title#01R - O: Notification Settings#01Z
```

**Expected Console output**

```
S: Account Settings#01T - W: Settings Title#01R - O: undefined
S: API Partner 1#01V - W: Settings Title#01R - O: API Settings#SOME-ID
S: API Partner 2#01X - W: Settings Title#01R - O: API Settings#SOME-ID
S: Notification Settings#01Z - W: Settings Title#01R - O: undefined
```

**Question**

What I don't understand is how the `require` gets the parent controllers. I'm expecting that `?^wizard-option` will give me the controller for the parent wizard-option directive if there is any. But it seems to be always `self` controller instead of the parents controller. I think it's related to the transclusion and to be honest I still don't understand what happens there exactly still after reading hundreds of explanation.

What I want to archive is defining the whole settings configuration in our DOM so it's pretty easy to see what settings are defined in a wizard. `partial` is just loading a form if there is no more nesting. The form could be added as a nested element as well. There is no limit for nestings.

The Idea if the view is to show only one level of options and after selecting an option it replaces the list of options with the list of the next level of nested elements or a form if there is one set instead. It's basically a tree which only shows on level at a time.

I did not include the controller because it's not about the view and controller itself, it's more related to the `require` for now. If I could get the correct `wizardOptionController` I could set there the correct `options`.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you could put this up in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Yes, will do it tomorrow. And I think I just figured out what it might be. Will prepare two fiddles for it maybe.